# Session lost after app restart with Redis + ASP.NET Core 3.1 + Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: asp.net-core, redis

I'm trying to use a Redis cache for maintaining session state between app restarts on an ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 website. However, when the app restarts, all the session information is lost.

Everything works fine in dev environment on my local (Mac) machine, but when deployed to an Ubuntu 18.04 server all the session info is lost between restarts.

The relevant code in my `Startup.cs` file looks like (lots of irrelevent stuff removed):

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();          
            services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
            {
                options.Configuration = "localhost";
                options.InstanceName = "sessionState";
            });
            
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(600);
            });

            var mvc = services.AddControllersWithViews();
            #if (DEBUG)
            mvc.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            #endif
            
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

The server is an Ubuntu 18.04 server, running ASP.NET Core 3.1 runtime.

Redis is installed and running and I can see a list of the session keys using the `redis-cli` and `keys *`. Running `sudo systemctl status redis` outputs:

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-01-05 03:36:30 UTC; 1h 10min ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 8916 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8920 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8950 (redis-server)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 1115)
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
           └─8950 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

I've tried various things to keep the session alive between app restarts, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question, mostly with the hope that this will help someone else in the future. This was a really tricky one and related to how the data protection capabilities work on a Linux server.

The crux of the solution is expressed very neatly in this issue on the dotnetcore GitHub (see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25801#issuecomment-715440092):

> You're on Linux. Data Protection cannot persist keys on linux without configuration, so it's using memory to hold the keyring, and when the app restarts, or you hit another instance of the app, where the keyring is different. Your logs will have had a warning on starting.
>
> You need to decide where the keyring should be stored (file system, redis, azure data storage, something else entirely) and configure data protection within your app to use it.

In my case, the actual solution is to store the data protection keys in the Redis cache along with the sessions (I think storing it anywhere but the default will work). I added the following to the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtectionKeys");
```

You'll also need to add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.StackExchangeRedis` nuget